# Residue Class Field Extensions separable

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I have two questions about arumentation steps of Prop. 8.4 in Neukirch's "Algebraic Number Theory" (p. 49):

How he concludes in the taged line of the attached image below that the residue class field extensions are generated by $\bar{\theta} = \theta \mod p_i$

and why this implicates that therefore these extension are separable?

[image]

Comment: I think it just comes down to $\bar \theta$ is a root of $\bar p(x)$ and $\mathcal{O}/\frak{P}_i$ are the splitting fileds of $\bar p(x)$ over $\mathcal{o}/\frak{p}_i$  Not sure why he says that the existence of a primitive element for $\mathcal{O}/\frak{P}_i$ over $\mathcal{o}/\frak{p}_i$ means the extension is separable.  In the case of number fields $\mathcal{o}/\frak{p}_i$ is perfect, so all extensions are separable.